# Conflicting changes detected EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, one-to-one

I have two table with one to one relation between them .Now I try to insert a record into parent table but get this error.

EF error:

> Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert
>   multiple entities with the same key.

MSSQL error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_TiwallReserve_TiwallPayment". The conflict occurred in database
>   "TravelEnterDB", table "dbo.TiwallPayment", column 'Id'.

```
    public bool saveTiwallReserve(TiwallReserve tiwallReserve){
       try{
        _db.TiwallReserves.Add(tiwallReserve);
        _db.SaveChanges();//get Error in this line
         }
      catch(Exeption e){
            string error=e.ErrorMessage;
                       }
        }
```

[image]
How to fix this?

Comment: We need to see the code that causes this error.

Comment: Your TiwallPayment table needs to have a matching key.  So add a record first to TiwallPayment, get the id and use it in the subsequent add to TiwallReserve.

Comment: TiwallPayment .Id is Foreign Key and primary key . TiwallReserve.Id is only primary key. I most first  insert recorde   into TiwallReserve